# Inserting multiple row in mysql with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple images with description in  codeigniter. Everything is fine, image is uploaded, image filename is sent to database however "description" is not going to database, where did i mistake ?

```
form code is like this 
  File 1: <input type="file" name="image1" /><br />
  Descr: <input type="text" name="description[]" size="50" value="" /><br/><br/>

  File 2: <input type="file" name="image2" /><br />
  Descr: <input type="text" name="description[]" size="50" value="" /><br/><br/>

  File 3:<input type="file" name="image3" /><br />
  Descr: <input type="text" name="description[]" size="50" value="" /><br/><br/>
```

and model is this

```
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
                    /* Handle the file upload */
                    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);
                    /* File failed to upload - continue */
                    if($upload === FALSE) continue;
                    /* Get the data about the file */
                    $data = $this->upload->data();

                    $uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;
                    /* If the file is an image - create a thumbnail */
                    if($data['is_image'] == 1) {
                        $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
                        $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
                        $this->image_lib->resize();
                    }


                        $image['raw'] = $data['raw_name'];
                        $image['ext'] = $data['file_ext'];
                        $image['newsid'] = $_POST['newsid'];
                        $image['description'] = $_POST['description'][$i];
                        $this->db->insert('multipics', $image);
                }
```

Please note that the above code makes multiple rows insertion, I just need the description field to go in database

Comment: did you use print_r($_POST)? is description posting or not.

Comment: yes description is posting     [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => gggg
            [1] => hhhhhhhhhhhhhh
            [2] => bbb
 
        )

Comment: use $this->db->last_query(), after $this->db->insert statement, is generating insertion statement properly or not.

Comment: Why do you write `image1`, `image2` instead of `image[]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around, I would get the POST variable first outside of the loop:

```
// (1) Get the POST description variable outside of the look     
// As a precaution, dump or echo $description to make sure it looks right...

$description_ = $this->input->post('description');


for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    ...
    // Put some checks to make sure $i is an index...
     $image['description'] = $description[$i];
    ...
}
```

Try this and let us know how you get on!

Answer (score 0):

Change Change name="description[]" to name="description

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at CI's [insert_batch()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) method. This will let you insert all of the records with one query.